# Zend Form Registration with

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I am new in Zend.
I have tried to create registration form in Zend.
I have get an array of form but it return false.

It returns me every time bye .
I don't know why???

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple:
First, create your registration form under **application/forms** or use zend tool

```
 zf enable form
 zf create form registration
```

this will create a file under **application/forms** entitled Registration.php

```
class Application_Form_Registration extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $firstname = $this->createElement('text','firstname');
        $firstname->setLabel('First Name:')
                    ->setRequired(false);

        $lastname = $this->createElement('text','lastname');
        $lastname->setLabel('Last Name:')
                    ->setRequired(false);

        $email = $this->createElement('text','email');
        $email->setLabel('Email: *')
                ->setRequired(false);

        $username = $this->createElement('text','username');
        $username->setLabel('Username: *')
                ->setRequired(true);

        $password = $this->createElement('password','password');
        $password->setLabel('Password: *')
                ->setRequired(true);

        $confirmPassword = $this->createElement('password','confirmPassword');
        $confirmPassword->setLabel('Confirm Password: *')
                ->setRequired(true);

        $register = $this->createElement('submit','register');
        $register->setLabel('Sign up')
                ->setIgnore(true);

        $this->addElements(array(
                        $firstname,
                        $lastname,
                        $email,
                        $username,
                        $password,
                        $confirmPassword,
                        $register
        ));
    }
}
```

This is a simple form with limited validation (only validation for fields that are required!)

Then you have to render the form in a view using the corresponding action:
as example in your UserController add action called

```
public function registerAction() {
        //send the form to the view (register)
        $userForm = new Application_Form_Registration();
        $this->view->form = $userForm;
       //check if the user entered data and submitted it
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            //check the form validation if not valid error message will appear under every required field
            if ($userForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams())) {
                //send data to the model to store it
                $userModel = new Application_Model_User();
                $userId = $userModel->addUser($userForm->getValues());
               }
            }

         }
```

The last two,  is to render the form in the view called **register**
using

```
<?= $this->form ?>
```

and add method in your model called **addUser()** to handle the insertion of data into the database